# Reading $_POST vars in JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, post

I would like to manipulate elements on a page based on user data (last name). I built a form, and uses post to update input data to php page. My thought was to get the $_POST value into the DOM: Then grab in JQuery:

Form page:

```
<form action="display.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="test" />
<input type="submit" value="go!!" />
</form>
```

Display.php

```
<?php
//store post value in var
$var = $_POST['test'];
?>
```

(above html)

```
<body>
<?php
echo '<form action="" method="">';
echo '<input type="hidden" class="grab" name="name1" value="' . $_POST['test'] . '">';
echo '</form>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

(in html)

script.js

```
var grab = $('input.grab').val();
document.write(grab);
```

I am a PHP newbie and realize that i am solving all my problems as a client side developer, not server side. Am I doing something terribly wrong? Or is there a better way

Comment: If you used GET instead of POST, you could just extract the value from the `window.location.search` query string using JavaScript.

Comment: If you're using javascript anyway, it seems almost easier to not post a form at all, and just capture the value of the input directly with an event handler ?

Comment: Just curious.. so you just want to show the value that was inputted right? If so why not just use all php to be consistent? Sorry i am quite new myself so just being curious

Comment: Just don't forget to execute the javascript on document ready $(document).ready(... and it'll be fine

Comment: @user1850712 - Still a php newbie. Wanted to hide/show different elements based on value passed from form, thought Jquery easiest way to do that. Using conditional: if lastname == "smith", hide all elemts with .test classname

Comment: @adeneo - Good point. decisions had to handled on separate page, figured PHP was easiest to pass multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

That's fine. Because JavaScript is a client-side language, this is a perfectly acceptable method of giving your JavaScript access to variables that are only available to the server.

You could also use something like:

```
<script>
    var myVar = '<?php echo $_POST['var']; ?>';
    console.log(myVar);
</script>
```

To prevent XSS and avoid issues with quotes in POST data, you should sanitize the output using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
<script>
    var myVar = '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['var'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?>';
    console.log(myVar);
</script>
```

Otherwise, $_POST['var'] = `'example` will break your JS and open up an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: You would obviously want to escape the output to prevent JS syntax errors or XSS attacks.

Comment: @JesseBunch I know. I just didn't want to complicate the answer. I will add another safer example though, just in case somebody decides to copy and paste.